# "Mit ein": wie soll man das benutzen?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Man sieht häufig die Formulierung **mit ein** in Satzteilen wie diesen:

- **mit ein paar…**
- **mit ein bisschen…**
- **mit ein wenig…**

Was ist der Kasus danach?
Warum ist es nicht **mit einen**?  Wann wäre es erlaubt und warum?

Comment: related:http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18884/meaning-of-nominative-genitive-dative-and-accusative/18887#18887

Comment: @Iris This question is the older one, if any of the two should be closed as duplicate, it should be the other one. This one just came to the front because the answer was edited (the link to canoo was updated).

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46632/ein-paar-or-einem-paar-in-dative

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf you are right.

Answer (score 7):

Der Präposition *mit* folgt der Dativ. Siehe dazu auch [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Dativ.html?MenuId=Word731#Anchor-mit-54980).

Beispiel:

> Das Team gewann mit Glück. Der Sieg wurde mit Bier gefeiert.

Dabei wird nicht selten die Menge an Glück/Bier definiert. Mit viel Glück oder mit ein bisschen/wenig Glück. Mit ein paar Bier oder doch nur einem Bier.

> Das Team gewann mit viel Glück. Der Sieg wurde mit ein paar Bier gefeiert.
>   Das Team mit ein bisschen/wenig Glück. Der Sieg wurde mit einem Bier gefeiert.

Offensichtlich handelt es sich in deinen Beispielen nicht um ein Konstrukt "mit ein", sondern um die Präposition *mit* gefolgt von dem Indefinitpronomen *ein paar*, *ein bisschen* oder *ein wenig*. Diese sind in der Regel unflektiert, wobei es hier ein paar Ausnahmen gibt. Auch hierzu siehe [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-bisschen.html?lang=de).

---

TL;DR:

- Präposition *mit* gefolgt vom Dativ
- Unflektiertes Indefinitpronomen

Comment: So!  Danke sehr.  Also, warum kann man "mit einem bisschen" sagen, aber nicht "mit einem wenig"?  Ist die Liste komplet mit diesen drei Beispiele?

Comment: Ob sie komplett ist, kann ich dir nicht sagen. Und das "warum" kann man denke ich auch nicht wirklich beantworten. Es ist halt so, wie's ist...

Comment: Aber das macht keinen Siiiinn :-(  Ach, Deutsch, du herbe Geliebte!

Comment: @Michaël, „bisschen“ und „paar“ waren mal Substantive. Das merkt man noch, und daher kann man sie auch noch so gebrauchen. Auf „wenig“ trifft das nicht zu.