# Ein Paar Fragen or Ein paar Fragen

Tags: grammatical-case

I am studying B2 German in the VHS. Today the teacher corrected the sentence:

> "Ich habe ein Paar Fragen"

to:

> "Ich habe ein paar Fragen"

But he couldn't explain why if "paar" isn't a noun  (and capitalised) the "ein" is declined as though it were. I mean "ein Paar" is correct but "ein Fragen" not.

Can someone explain this anomaly

Comment: Ein _Paar_ can be considered a noun if you exactly mean a 2 couple. Ein _paar_ generally means _several_.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ That doesn't answer the question I asked which is why is the indefinite article declined as though for a neutral noun.

Comment: _"That doesn't answer the question"_ That's why I posted a comment. _"Ich habe ein Fragen"_ sounds just awkward.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8555/does-paar-still-mean-two-items-words-that-have-lost-their-original-meaning

Comment: No, that discussion is again about the differrence between ein Paar (a couple) and ein paar (a few). My question is about the declination of the indefinate article in the second instance "...ein paar Fragen".

Comment: Maybe this question helps? https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32462/is-it-seit-ein-paar-tagen-or-seit-einen-paar-tagen Or this one: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46632/ein-paar-or-einem-paar-in-dative

Comment: @David Vogt Thanks. '"Ein" is a part of "ein paar" and "ein paar" is an unchangeable pronoun.' seems to explain it. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Think of "ein paar" as a fixed expression. It's just how it is...

Comment: It's not "just how it works". OP's spelling was not incorrect. It's not correct either, and German education is too fixated on formal correctness where there is none--is what this is. /rant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Das Paar* is a noun and therefore the article is declined as in

> ein Paar (nominative)
>
> eines Paares (genitive)
>
> einem Paar (dative)
>
> ein Paar (accusative).

*Ein paar* in **ein paar Fragen** however is a fixed expression. Therein *ein* isn't an indefinite article but just a part
of the expression like in

> *ein paar* Fragen (some questions)
>
> *ein wenig* Zucker (some sugar)
>
> *ein bisschen* Zeit (a bit of time).

*Ein wenig ...* and *ein bisschen ...* are equivalent to [etwas](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/etwas). For countable things one uses *ein paar* instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. That answers my question!

Answer (score 7):

There is the noun "[ein Paar](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Paar)", which means two associated humans or objects (das glückliche Paar = the happy couple, die Paar Schuhe = the pair of shoes)
and there is the pronoun "[paar](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/paar_einige_wenige)" which means some or few and which is often combined as a [fixed expression as "ein paar](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein_paar)".

Examples:

> alle paar Wochen = every few weeks
>
> ein paar Menschen = some people

So the meaning determines to capitalization:

> Ich habe ein paar Schuhe = I have a few (pairs of) shoes
>
> Ich habe ein Paar Schuhe = I have one pair of shoes

---

In regard of your question: "Ein paar Fragen" refers to few/some questions as questions are *usually* not handled in pairs. In questionnaires and games that's sometimes the case and - as @hajef pointed out - in that specific case, "ein Paar Fragen" would be correct, thought one usually would say "ein Fragenpaar".

I actually never heard someone use ein Paar Fragen in the meaning of one pair of questions or "Fragenpaar". I think, it's more common to use "zwei zusammengehörende Fragen" (= two related questions)

Comment: Do you think it is useful to add that "ein Paar Fragen" is very uncommon for "Fragen"?

Comment: Qestions are not _usually_ handled in pairs. In case of jokes or riddles there might well be two questions that are only meaningful together. In that specific case, "ein Paar Fragen" would be correct, thought one usually would say "ein Fragenpaar".

Comment: 'ein paar Fragen' (a few) is quite common in colloquial (spoken) language. 'Ein Paar Fragen' (a pair) would require a special context.

Comment: One may, in special situations, have ein "Fragen-Paar". This then implies that there are two questions, and they are interrelated. Could for example happen in a quiz were always two questions at once have to be answered. But that's a very special situation of course.

Comment: This "answer"  is again about the difference between ein Paar (a couple) and ein paar (a few). My question is about the declination of the indefinate article in the second instance "...ein paar Fragen". This "answer" doesn't answer my question at all. David Vogt gave a link above which contained the statement  '"Ein" is a part of "ein paar" and "ein paar" is an unchangeable pronoun.' and this comes closest to answering my actual question.

Comment: @Steve It’s sadly become quite customary in this community to ignore the actual question and answer a similar, common question that German learners often have instead... and those answers even get upvotes.